# XSLT: Adding a node!

Tags: xslt

How do I encapsulate nodes around my XML blocks using XSLT?
For example, I have the following XML file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <Root>
      <VOBaseCollection>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Root/Location" />
      </VOBaseCollection>
    </Root>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My input XML file looks like this.

```
  <Root>
<Location><Name>Pennsylvania</Name><Type>State</Type></Location>
</Root>
```

I wish the output to look like this.

```
      <Root><Container>
    <Location><Name>Pennsylvania</Name><Type>State</Type></Location>
</Container>
    </Root>
```

I wish to make sure that a node called `<CONTAINER>` gets applied every time, it copies over information from Root/Location. What changes do I need to do to my XSLT file?

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. How about you provide a small sample XML file and the output you're hoping to get?

Comment: My XML file looks like this.
[code]
<Root>
  <Location>
    <NAME>Pennsylvania</NAME>
<TYPE>State</TYPE>
</Location>
</Root>
[/code]
I wish to transform this file into
[code]
<Root>
<Container>
<Location>
<Name>Pennsylvania</Name>
<Type> State </Type>
</Location>
</Container>
</Root>
[/code]

Comment: Then what is `<VOBaseCollection>` in your example? If you rename that to `<Container>` it looks like you'll have exactly what you want.

Comment: Container has to appear multiple times. The basecollection tag appears once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summarizing all the answers in comments, this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()" name="identity">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Location">
        <Container>
            <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
        </Container>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Result:

```
<Root>
    <Container>
        <Location>
            <Name>Pennsylvania</Name>
            <Type>State</Type>
        </Location>
    </Container>
</Root>
```

Answer (score 1):

**I am just guessing, and *in guess mode* it seems that you want this**:

**EDIT**: helped by another guess by Mads Hansen...

**Add** this to the identity template you already have:

```
<xsl:template match="Location">
  <CONTAINER><xsl:apply-templates/></CONTAINER>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: There is no CONTAINER in my XML document, so where will it do the matching?

Comment: @abhi: You haven't shown any XML document and *this* is the real problem... When you say: "I wish to make sure that a node called `<CONTAINER>` gets applied every time" -- I understand that there is a `<CONTAINER>` in the XML document and you wish that every time it is matched (a template is applied to it), then a certain processing (copying of `Root/Location`) must be done.

Please, edit your question and define it better. Also, provide a minimal XML document!

Comment: @Dimitre - He wants to match on `Location` and wrap with `Container`: `<xsl:template match="Location">
 <Container>
  <xsl:call-template name="identity" />
 </Container>
  </xsl:template>`

Comment: @abhi: Probably the latest edit in my answer finally produces your desired result?

Comment: @Dimitre, Your latest solution gives me the container tag wrapped around the xml, but gets rid of the child nodes. In this case my output changes to
<CONTAINER>
Pennsylvnia
State
</CONTAINER>

Comment: @abhi: This means that you don't have the identity template. It is in your code, I just provided the one additional template you must have.

Comment: That's correct. The only template I have is the one you see in my original question.

Comment: @abhi: In your question there are *two* templates. The identity template is this one (as copied from your question and now pasted):

`  <xsl:template match="@*|node()"> 
      <xsl:copy> 
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" /> 
    </xsl:copy> 
  </xsl:template> 
`